# How to accelerate (parallelize ?) a text file editing?

Tags: python, io

I have a script that delete the second line if it has a certain pattern. However when ran on a folder that contains hundreds of files it is pretty slow, I have to wait 5 minutes or so for it to complete. Since it's i/o I'm sure there is a way to accelerate or parallelize it do you know how ? Here is the current slow code :

```
import datetime as dt
import os, re

for symb in os.listdir(r'C:\folder'):

    n1=dt.datetime.now()

    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()

    new_file = open(abs_path,'w')

    file_path = r'C:\folder' + '\\' + symb

    print(repr(file_path))

    old_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    new_file = open(abs_path, 'w')

    data = old_file.readlines()


    if re.match('9:', data[1]):
        print('YES')
        del data[1]

    for line in data :
        new_file.write(line)

    new_file.close()
    close(fh)
    old_file.close()


    remove(file_path)

    move(abs_path, file_path)

    print(symb + ' : ' + str((dt.datetime.now()-n1).microseconds))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely disk bound, but you could tighten up the code a bit by doing larger block copies. Instead of readlines/writelines, process the first two lines manually and then turn it over to shutil for the rest.

```
import shutil

....

    line1 = oldfile.readline()
    line2 = oldfile.readline()
    if re.match('9:', line2):
        line2 = ''
    newfile.write(line1 + line2)
    shutil.copyfileobj(old_file, new_file, length=1024*1024)
```

You could see if you are disk bound by doing an xcopy of all the files and seeing if the time is about the same. if you have multiple hard drive, you should make sure that the intermediate file is on the same drive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the `multiprocessing` module. For example, you could use `Pool` to map a function over the list of files in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5)
def doIt(x):
    # do the thing

p.map(doIt, os.listdir(r'C:\folder'))
```